# Install ORDS with Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to print reports in PDF format using apex 4.2.2 or v5. I have read that ORDS v3 is required to work even after enabling PDF in instance setting under apex admin.

But during installation it halted the process as

[image]

and when I check the URL it shows the following ouptut:

**Debug Trace**

```
mapped request using: /* to: PLSQL:apex  Could not find any dispatcher to handle request: --Attributes-- nanoStart = 1447556222844 apex.diagnostic.context = Attempting to process as a Dispatchable Service  ECID-Principal = ECIDPrincipal [ecid=qKmpkwa3M59vpxfWvdonuA..] oracle.dbtools.http.ecid = co0K1af4SoL_vfSvpOewLA.. oracle.dbtools.common.di.Services = Request Scope --Attributes-- GET /ords/ HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1 Cookie: WWV_CUSTOM-F_4876305575366759_100=A232DDB1270CE7EC; WWV_CUSTOM-F_4876305575366759_101=CDDDBA5608605CD8; WWV_CUSTOM-F_10_4950=E5A43E72CA2546A0 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 Connection: keep-alive User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36 Host: 127.0.0.1:8090 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8   HttpInputOverHTTP@b9a27
```

**Stack Trace**

```
NotFoundException [statusCode=404, reasons=[]] at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.choose(Dispatcher.java:82) at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:92) at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:123) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73) at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:82) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:59) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:67) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:61) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:89) at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:62) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.PLSQLMapper.doFilter(PLSQLMapper.java:37) at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMapping.doFilter(URLMapping.java:78) at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:63) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.locale.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:60) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:71) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:75) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.ecid.ECIDFilter.doFilter(ECIDFilter.java:35) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:45) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64) at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:47) at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:80) at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:46) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchableServices(HttpEndpointBase.java:166) at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:88) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There isn't much of a community on ORDS on SO, not even a tag yet. Your targetted audience is most likely not to be found here. I personally can't offer much help on built-in PDF printing (and the oracle-apex community isn't that big on SO either... Especially for specific technical cases like this). Your best resources are: [OTN ORDS](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/oracle_rest_data_services) or [OTN Apex](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/application_express). Very active communities, even the Oracle devs there.

Comment: I have already posted at https://community.oracle.com/thread/3819251 but not get enough help.

Comment: Where did you install ORDS? standalone? I strongly recommend using something like Glassfish to run your ORDS instance. I can't get much information from your trace, but there are a lot of "validateConnection" messages in the stack so it might be an authentication problem. Can you give some more info on your architecture please?

Comment: Installed glassfish, but no improvement

Comment: Seeing the top of the stack trace from the installer would be much more helpful

Comment: If you are already using Apex without ORDS - that is, using the embedded PL/SQL gateway in the database as the web listener - I rather doubt you would need to use ORDS to support PDF conversion.  Where did you get that info?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using apex 5.0 then you do not need the ords users. So do **not** do

```
java -jar ords.war install
```

Since that will take you through the process of creating **ords_metadata** and **ords_public_user**, which you do not need with Apex. But rather use

First step, define location:

```
java -jar ords.war configdir c:\ords\
```

(it will create another ords directory under your specified directory)

Next step, define the APEX server + passwords (apex_public_user and apex_listener+apex_rest_public_user if using rest services),

```
java -jar ords.war setup
```

This will run you through a setup process.

Next you have a few options to run apex, 1) standalone 2) Java server (Glassfish, Tomcat, weblogic)

Standalone is pretty straight forward:

```
java -jar ords.war standalone --port 8080 --apex-images c:\ords\i\
```

You need the **images** folder from the Apex 5.0 zip to be c:\ords\i\ (or change the location)

Setting up on Tomcat is pretty simple. After extracting Tomcat, just copy ords.war to the webapps folder and copy the apex 5.0 images folder to webapps\i\

Note that you need to run the java -jar ords.war configdir on the same machine as the tomcat server and tomcat needs access to that folder.

If you mess up the set-up simply remove the **c:\ords\ords** folder and re-run the setup process.  You can also define a new configdir and try again while keeping the old one, Note that running configdir will always create a subfolder and put the setting files there.

Also make sure that apex_public_user is unlocked and you have the correct password, i.e.

```
sqlplus apex_public_user/*your password*@server
```

Should connect you and you should be able to do

```
select * from dual;
```

--edit--

Make sure that you have Oracle's Java installed and that is being used to run ords:

```
C:\>java -version java
```

Should give something like

```
version "1.8.0_31" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If I have already run install command? Since I also done configdir command but will do it again as explained

Comment: my basic concern is why process is being halted as shown in picture above? SinceI already did same procedure almost.

Comment: It doesn't find any thing to run.  (404) So there is something wrong.  Apex 5.0 is correctly set up? and apex_public_user is open?    Apex 5.0 and ORDS 3 are separate installs.

Comment: Also look for defaults.xml to find your previous install

Comment: Yes, I have installed both separately

Comment: ok,  Then it should work if you follow my steps.  I have set up dozens of Apex 5.0 + ORDS 3.x in different scenarios.  Do the "setup" part and try running it.  As long as the apex install finished correctly and you have access to the database + images from apex 5.0, my steps will work.

Comment: Is there any Windows requirements? 32 bit will work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99774/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-olafur-tryggvason).